# How do I run the system commands in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to list all the files in the JavaScript thingy, such as using "ls".

Comment: You are talking about executing commands server-side, correct? Not on the client browser?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unprivileged JavaScript in a browser can neither list files nor execute programs for security reasons.

In [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js), for example, executing programs works like this:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
var ls  = spawn('ls', ['-l']);
ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

And there is a direct way to list files using [readdir()](http://utahjs.com/2010/09/16/nodejs-events-and-recursion-readdir/).

Comment: I suppose this is going to run on a server. What about pure JavaScript to run on the client? Just for security testing.

Answer (score 7):

You can't run system commands on the client with JavaScript since it works inside a browser sandbox. You'd need to use some other client-side tech like [Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash), [ActiveX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) or maybe [applets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet).

Comment: I think Applets also run in a sandbox.

Answer (score 5):

An even easier way in node.js is:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ls = fs.readdirSync('/usr');
```

The variable `ls` now contains an array with the filenames at /usr.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you can not run any system command. This will violate the security model. You can do send a print command, but I wonder anything beyond that is possible.

Comment: Is that an heresy to say that if someone can access the stdout then somehow other system calls also could be invoked after passing some security barrier?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: you should *not* do this as it opens a huge attack vector against your application. Imagine someone running `"rm -rf"` :).

If you *must* do this and you are 1000% sure you allow only a few commands which cannot cause any harm you can call a server page using Ajax. That page could run the specified command and return response. Again I emphasize this is a huge security risk and should better *not* be done.

Comment: Related conversation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41088671/asp-net-c-sharp-mvc-website-how-can-i-mount-a-drive-upon-button-click

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like the program you run give out output that uses [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (for example, to print out the progress percentage on the screen):

I wasn't able to do that on macOS unless I use the following (I am using [macOS v13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura)):

```js
const { spawn } = require("node:child_process");

const commandProcess = spawn(
  "node",
  ["someScript.js", "someArg1", "someArg2"],
  {
    stdio: "inherit"
  }
);
```

This will show all the [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29), [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)), etc., on screen, as if it is a command typed into a shell.  This is [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processspawncommand-args-options).