# Run a .jar file with parameters from JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Execute another jar in a java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program)

I have an executable jar file that accepts two parameters: an input file and an output file:

```
java -jar inputFile.txt outputFile.txt
```

How can I call exactly this from JavaScript?

Comment: I'm hoping you understand the complete and utter difference between Java and JavaScript. Are you building a website or web application?

Comment: I've edited the question so that it makes some sense. If you don't find the edits appropriate, please roll them back.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320476/execute-another-jar-in-a-java-program

Comment: @Blender: That changes the meaning of the question. The original was about how to call it from JavaScript, not Java, which is a perfectly reasonable (if uncommon) thing to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer depends on the context.

- If your javascript is running in a web browser sandbox, then the answer is that you can't run a JAR file.  The sandbox is designed to stop you doing that kind of thing.
- If your javascript is running under node.js, then this SO Q&A offers a solution to the problem of running a command: 
   [How do I run the system commands in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321884/how-do-i-run-the-system-commands-in-javascript).  This can be used to run the `java` command with the appropriate args.
- If your javascript is trusted code running in a browser with a Java plugin, then you *may* be able to make a call to `java.lang.System.exec(...)` passing an appropriate `java` command line in the appropriate fashion.  You *may* also be able to create a classloader, read the JAR file's manifest, extract the entry point class, load it, and call the "main" method.

Answer (score -5):

```
java -jar executable.jar inputFile.txt outputFile.txt
```

For further details see the [java command synopsis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#synopsis):

**SYNOPSIS**

- java [ options ] class [ argument ... ]
- **java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ argument ... ]**
- javaw [ options ] class [ argument ... ]
- javaw [ options ] -jar file.jar [ argument ... ]