# How can i call jar API from javascript using node.js with more implementations steps

Tags: javascript, java, jar

I am trying to re-use the code in different technology stack.
Let's say:
I have a jar which contatins followng class defination:

```
package com.gallop;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GenerateFile {

    public void generateFile(String fileName)
    {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the code is exported to filegenerator.jar.

Now, question is how can i use the class inside filegenerator.jar to create a file using javascript. Basically, I have import GenerateFile class for jar. I have to create instance of GenerateFile. Then using instance of GenerateFile, i should be able to invoke method generateFile with filePath as parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a .jar file with parameters from JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822418/run-a-jar-file-with-parameters-from-javascript)

Comment: Create the file where exactly? And javascript from where? In a browser? Node.js?