# Is it possible to use Java methods from *.jar files in angular 5 services?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, user-interface, angular5

I am new to Angular, I am wondering if there is any possibility of importing *.jar files inside Angular 5 components or Services. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Maybe. See [*calling java methods in javascript code*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6649204/1260204) and [*Run a .jar file with parameters from JavaScript*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11822943/1260204)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea, and it's too broad to ask here. Typically, you want to consume java 'code' from a WebApi from angular. You really don't want to install .jar to all the clients computers

Comment: Perhaps if you explain what exactly you want to do, you will find better options than import jar files in an angular project