# Can a .jar file or any other externally packaged library be called in Angular application on a button click?

Tags: angular, typescript, shared-libraries

I am a beginner in Angular and I am planning on creating a UI using it. Is there any way that if the user clicks a button, the app calls or references a .jar or any other externally packaged library? If so, can anyone explain how to include that library in my app project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For most situation the answer is no. For details you'd have to describe how your app should work. Do you plan to create a standalone or is it a web app that gets data from a sever? What type of functionality do you want to use from your jar file, ... See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52412891/is-it-possible-to-use-java-methods-from-jar-files-in-angular-5-services

Comment: Hi @ChristophLütjen. It is a web app that gets data from a server. For example, the functionality of the library(which can be any format not only jar) can be understood to be connecting to a device using some connection properties and protocols.

Comment: Would be nice if you can edit your question accordingly