# How to use R package inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, r

I m developing a web application using D3.js now and it requires some statistical techniques. I know there are excellent R packages out that has implemented the techniques I need nicely. My question is, how can I use the R Package inside my JavaScript code? I mean to call the R functions directly from my JavaScript code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked this library? http://www.jstat.org/. Maybe that helps.

Comment: I did, but I need to do projection pursuit and jstat doesn't have it. The best package I found that has PP implemented is an R package, not even matlab.

Comment: It seems you are using **D3.js** on the server side, or else how can you make the JavaScript code call R from browser? If the former is really what you target, then refer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321884/how-do-i-run-the-system-commands-in-javascript) for using R as your analysis engine.