# Openl JNLP/web start app from browser

Tags: javascript, plugins, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, jnlp

I have a browser with my application running on it and I have one JNLP application installed on my system.
So from browser how do we launch the installed JNLP application.

I know we cannot do it from JavaScript/jquery.

So is there any plugin/extension that will do my work.
Or
can I write some kind of plugin/extension for browser that will invoke my JNLP application.

If Yes how do i proceed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run anything Natively, you need to use NPAPI. That allows you to run code outside the sandbox for your extensions.

[http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi)

Comment: But NPAPI plugin support is disabled/stopped. Any other way apart from NPAPI

Comment: Check this answer for a different workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/5321989/1225070