# Access file from user system while running code from live server django

Tags: python-3.x, django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I want to access and execute .bat file from end-user system while my code running on server.
Indirectly I want to access local system file of user system.

Python / Django solution.

Comment: HTML/JS does not allow you to access the user file system due to it being a great security risk. You could upload the file, and run that, but that would, again, be a massive security risk.

Comment: @nigel239 .exe file not run ubuntu server.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321884/how-do-i-run-the-system-commands-in-javascript it says something about ActiveX or applets.